# Is ist possible to get the page variables in node templates?

Tags: 7, theming

I set a variable by implementing the `hook hook_preprocess_page`. The variable is available in `$variables['my_custom_var']` within the page.tpl.php.

Is it possible to get access to this variable in node.tpl.php or any other node template?

Comment: I set a variable by implementing the hook hook_preprocess_page. The variable is available in $variables['my_custom_var'] within the page.tpl.php. Is it possible to get access to this variable in node.tpl.php or any other node template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables that you set in the *hook_preprocess_page* are not available in *node.tpl.php*, only the variables in the *hook_preprocess_node* are available in  *node.tpl.php*. Also the variables in *hook_preprocess_node* are not available in *page.tpl.php*

To share the varialbes between them you can use static variables. To do so use this code

```
function _myTheme_var($var_name, $new_val = NULL) {
  $vars = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());

   // If a new value has been passed
  if ($new_val) {
    $vars[$var_name] = $new_val;
  }

  return isset($vars[$var_name]) ? $vars[$var_name] : NULL;
}

function myTheme_preprocess_page(&$vars){
  $vars['some_var'] = _myTheme_var('my_var', 7); // Set the value and retrieve it
}

function myTheme_preprocess_node(&$vars){
    $vars['some_var'] = _myTheme_var('my_var'); // Get the value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `node.tpl.php` you can render the particular field like this:

```
echo render($content['field_header']);
hide($content['field_header']); // This line isn't necessary as the field has already been rendered, but I've left it here to show how to hide part of a render array in general.
```

If you need to do this in `page.tpl.php` then you want to implement a preprocess function in your template file to get the variable you need:

```
function mymodule_preproces_page(&$vars) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object() && $node->type == 'page') {
    $view = node_view($node);
    $vars['my_header'] = render($view['field_header']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables in [template_preprocess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7) for the node template